# Cannot add NuGet feed to Azure Dev Ops artifacts

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-artifacts

I have a NuGet feed for another source of packages for my project that I'd like to add to the Azure Dev Ops artifacts section as an upstream source, joining the standard NuGet feed. However, despite what the documentation says (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/how-to/set-up-upstream-sources?view=azure-devops), the only custom option I see is for "custom NPN registry" with a note saying npm is the only package type that supports custom public upstream sources.

I added my feed anyway but it's not findable in Visual Studio's package manager, though I was able to add something from the standard NuGet feed. Is there a setting I'm missing to enable custom NuGet feeds to be added in, or are the docs incorrect here?

Comment: Did you confirm that you have sufficient permissions? Are you using Azure DevOps Server or TFS on-prem, or Azure DevOps cloud (i.e. PaaS)? The feature definitely exists in Azure DevOps.

Comment: I changed accounts to the devops owner one of mine and I still had the same result. Maybe something's changed or busted right now? This is DevOps cloud, the dev.azure.com address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are misreading the documentation.

> Custom public upstream sources are only supported with npm registries.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/how-to/set-up-upstream-sources?view=azure-devops#enable-upstream-sources-in-an-existing-feed

If you want to use a single feed for everything, you'll have to implement a bit of a hacky workaround.

The workaround, as unfortunate as it may be, would be to use a scheduled pipeline to synchronize the external feed with your Azure DevOps feed.

Comment: How to explain my test sample? And the document said that the custom **public** upstream sources are only supported with npm registries, however, we use the custom **private** upstream sources not the public.